# How can I display the foreign key model value of a modelformset_factory?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Lets say I have models:

```
  class model1(model.Models):
    name = CharField(max_length = 20)
    phone = IntegerField(max_length = 20)

  class model2(model.Models):
    name = ForeignKeyFeild(model1)
    team = CharField(max_length = 20)
```

If I set up a modelformset factory like so in a view:

```
  qset = model2.objects.all()
  fset = modelformset_factory(model2, fields = ('team', 'name')
  form = fset(queryset = qset)
```

In templates how can I show the value of 'phone'  from model1?

When I render the form in the template:

```
 {% for f in form %}
  {{f.team.value}} # this gives me the value without an input field
  {{f.name.phone}} # this however renders nothing and that's what I'm trying to find out
 {%endfor%}
```

How can I make the {{f.name.phone}} which is information from the table where it holds a foreign_key show?